# Reasons that LIME and SHAP might not agree with intuition

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, shap

[Edit: Discussion moved to stat.stackexchange.com, link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445726/reasons-that-lime-and-shap-might-not-agree-with-intuition)]

I'm leveraging the Python packages `lime` and `shap` to explain single (test-set) predictions that a basic, trained model is making on new, tabular data. WLOG, the explanations generated by both methods do not agree with user intuition.

For example, when leveraging the methods in a healthcare setting, they might list the presence of a comorbidity (a disease that frequently co-occurs with the outcome disease of interest) as a factor that *decreases* a patient's risk of an adverse event.

Intuitively, such behavior is incorrect. We shouldn't see that `history of heart attacks` *lowers* the `risk of adverse events`, for example. What are some reasons that we might see these inconsistencies?

**Some of my ideas**

- Class label imbalance: tried balancing the dataset, did not solve the issue
- Kernel width for LIME: working on tuning this, but cursorily, no benefit
- Relationship to training data: for tabular data, both `lime` and `shap` require the training dataset as input to build the explainer class. If there are instances in which a feature such as `history of heart attacks` were associated with a `no adverse event` outcome, such instances would "confuse" the methods, so to speak. However, I'm not sure I have the intuition correct there.
- Error in understanding on my part: there may be nuances in intuition here that I've missed. Specifically, I am trying to make sure I correctly understand the relationship between the generated explanations and the training dataset used to build them.

Comment: I think this might be better asked at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @PaulH, I've moved it over